# Forge Developer's Guide Prepare Cloud Storage - Issue with uploading a file to signed url

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge, autodesk-designautomation

I am following the [Design Automation API for Revit Step by Step Tutorial.](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/step6-prepare-cloud-storage/)

I am stuck at the prepare cloud storage - step 3 where I upload a file to the signed url.

I keep getting this error:

```
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
```

I copy paste the signed url I get from the response of step 2 so there shouldn't be any issue with signature.

Comment: Ok, and you are doing this on a PUT call and also passing in the Data Binary of the file to be uploaded. Are you doing this immediately after creating the presignedURL?  I retested the tutorial, everything seems ok. How big is your file, file size shouldn't be an issue but if you are doing chunks might not be done correctly.

Comment: @JaimeRosales Thank you very much. I didn't pay any attention to the request type because I just copied and pasted the curl command to the postman. Somehow postman imported the put request as a post request so I was getting auth error. Now my issue is solved. :) Could you write this as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: done added as an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing this on a PUT call and also passing in the Data Binary of the file to be uploaded.